# Pip SSLError WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER under proxy

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, pip, anaconda

I use Python 3.8.5 with an Anaconda virtual environment. I need to use *pip* in order to install some python packages in my environment. But for any package installation, I get an error relating a SSL error and a wrong version number :

[Ubuntu prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjEB6.png)

Note that my company uses a proxy but variables `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are all set properly and I have already tried to use the pip option `--proxy`. I have searched a lot for solutions on different forums but none of its help me to solve my problem. Even if you can't solve it, I would be very grateful if I can have some explanations on this bug. For example :

- why SSL talks about wrong version number ?
- Is this problem necessarily linked to the proxy ?

Also note that that my OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT :

[Steffen Ulrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich) found the problem : the `https_variable` was set to `https://proxy` instead of `http://proxy`. Thanks a lot Steffen !

Comment: *"... http_proxy, https_proxy, HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY are all set properly ... "* - Doubt, and you don't actually show this. My guess is that you've set the `https_proxy` environment variable to `https://proxy` instead of `http://proxy` in the assumption that the proxy itself gets accessed by https - which is likely wrong.

Comment: Which is clearly correct and works for everything with moderate quality, but not pip....

Answer (score 7):

The https_variable should be set to `http://proxy` instead of `https://proxy`

So, before anything else, just run this command:

For Windows:

```
set https_proxy=http://login:password@address:port
```

For Ubuntu:

```
export https_proxy=http://login:password@address:port
```

Comment: How did you know to do this (switch from "https" to "http")? Is there a book where I can read more about this?

Answer (score 0):

For me I have the issue on both Python 3.9 and 3.8 with Windows 10.

The solution for me remarkable as it is was to UNSET the proxy at the Windows level (in internet explorer)

Paste this into Windows + R (run promt) then uncheck all the proxy settings.

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL inetcpl.cpl,,4
```

Then in your pip command set the proxy

```
pip install package --proxy http://proxy:3128
```

[Confirmed a bug exists when system proxy is set pip ignores the command line](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9568)